# Correct way to use redux with async data loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await

I'm using `redux` to load data from the backend in a `react` application. I'm loading a bunch of data with axios and then I can select one item and see the specific information in a different view. I'm rendering a "Loading" view every time I do a search in the backend. The problem is: this search is fine whenever I load the view refreshing the browser. But when I'm navigating in the own app, I use `react-router-dom` and I don't need to show the loading screen because it is already in the redux store.

Is there a way to tell redux or react to not make the async call if I already have the data?

Is [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) a solution for this? Should I do it manually with a condition in react?

I make the call in the `componentDidMount` method

Comment: Please post the code for the component in which you have your `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method and ensure you include the `import` statements as well. Also, when you say loading view, are you referring to a spinner or just some text that says `Loading...`? Please post that code as well. Are you calling an action creator from `componentDidMount()`? Again post all the relevant code.

Comment: @Daniel I'm asking a theoretical question, I don't see how this is relevant to the question. That's why I didn't put any code.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data from redux store down to your component as a property and you should make a check in `componentDidMount` or before that if data is empty or null or whatever and make a decision if you should load it after that. You don't need any 3rd party lib for data persistence (like `redux-persist`) since you actually have it in your redux store already persisted.